# how can I use lines in a file as arg and append a prefix to each arg in bash?

Tags: bash

I have a file like this:

```
arg1
arg2
arg3
...
argN
```

I knew I can use xargs for this `cat input.txt | xargs <my command>`. However, I would like to append a prefix to each args so the result should be `<my command> prefix/arg1 prefix/arg2 ...`

The `-I` cannot work because it implies -L 1 and -x.

Comment: From a practical viewpoint: How about modifying `my command` so that it accepts a prefix (either as first argument, or via the environment) and applies it to each of its arguments? If you can't modify the command itself, you can write a wrapper which performs this task.

Comment: Note that `-I` implying `-L1` is specific to the GNU implementation of `xargs`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `bash` is tagged, you could have them as array and substitute the beginning `#` of each item with your prefix using [Shell Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```sh
mapfile -t args < input.txt
<my command> "${args[@]/#/prefix/}" # <my command> prefix/arg1 prefix/arg2 …
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use `sed` to change the lines before piping them into `xargs`

```sh
sed 's/^/prefix\//' input.txt | xargs <my command>
```